# Adding / removing classes when scrolling on multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was using a script (that I probably found here) to add / remove classes on elements while scrolling. The scripts associates **href** from a menu to add / remove classes to corresponding element in the page. The script works fine when using one menu and one set of elements, but I tried to make it usable with multiple menus and I can't seem to find what's wrong. I get an error with the **getTargetTop()** function, but I can't resolve it.

Here is the code I'm using :

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    checkSectionSelected($(window).scrollTop());
});

function getTargetTop(elem){
    console.log(elem.attr('href'));
    var id = elem.attr("href");
    var offset = 0;
    return $(id).offset().top - offset;
}

var sections = $('ul.ctrl a');
var mainmenu = $('nav a');

function checkSectionSelected(scrolledTo){

var threshold = 100;

var i;

for (i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {

    var section = $(sections[i]);
    var target = getTargetTop(section);

    if (scrolledTo > target - threshold && scrolledTo < target + threshold) {
        $('.char').removeClass('active');
        $('.char'+section.attr('href')).addClass('active');
        sections.parent('li').siblings('li').removeClass("active");
        section.parent('li').addClass("active");
    }
};

var m;

for (m = 0; m < mainmenu.length; m++) {
    var link = $(mainmenu[m]);
    var newTar = getTargetTop(link);
    if (scrolledTo > newTar - threshold && scrolledTo < newTar + threshold) {
        sections.parent('li').siblings('li').removeClass("active");
        section.parent('li').addClass("active");
    }

};

}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Well what's the error that you are getting? It should be logged in the console of your browser.

Comment: You should look into using the .each() method to loop through your jQuery elements rather than that ugly for loop.